# How to restore a builtin when parameter has same name?

Tags: python, parameters, built-in

I know you're "[not supposed to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417979/can-i-use-variable-name-type-as-function-argument-in-python)" use builtin names as parameters for functions, but sometimes they make the most sense:

```
def foo(range=(4,5), type="round", len=2):
```

But if this has been done, and the `range` variable has been processed and is no longer needed, how do I get back to the builtin `range` and use it inside `foo()`?

[`del range`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17152796/125507) doesn't restore the builtin:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'range' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Range of what? Range of response times? Range of fuel efficiencies? There should be something you can roll into the name to differentiate from the generic built-in.

Comment: Obviously it's a range of `foo`s. ;)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 range of foo, obviously.  `foo(foo_range=(4,5))` would be redundant. :)

Comment: `del range` works at global scope because it removes `range` from the global namespace, and global lookups check the builtin namespace after the global namespace. It does not work at local scope because it removes `range` from the local namespace, but the variable is *still looked up as a local, and only as a local*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html#module-__builtin__)

```
import __builtin__
range = __builtin__.range
```

For [Python 3.x](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/builtins.html#module-builtins)

```
import builtins
range = builtins.range
```

Answer (score 3):

Also for both python versions, you can use `__builtins__` without importing anything.

Example -

```
>>> def foo(range=(4,5)):
...     print(range)
...     range = __builtins__.range
...     print(range)
...
>>> foo()
(4, 5)
<class 'range'>
```

Comment: these answers all say that you shouldn't do that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11181519/125507