# what is del doing to builtins when they are defined for variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

If someone uses a python builtin as a variable, deleting the variable seems to revert the definition of the term to the original definition. For example:

```
set = 1
print(set)
del set
a = set([1,2,3])
print(a)
```

Result:

```
1
{1, 2, 3}
```

However, when you delete a builtin from the start, it is no longer defined:

```
del set
a = set([1,2,3])
print(a)
```

Result:
`NameError: name 'set' is not defined`

I understand that it is bad practice to use builtins as variables, but I'm curious about this design decision:

***If the python source code can intelligently restore deleted variables by assigning them to their original builtin value, why does the code allow the deletion of builtins in my second example? What possible utility could there be in allowing the deletion of builtins?***

No I don't have a real world use case for this; I just want to understand the design decision.

Comment: That's a great link, thanks

Comment: So, this works analogously to `class A: foo = 'bar'; a = A(); a.foo = 'baz'; print(a.foo); del a.foo; print(a.foo)`

Comment: @user2357112 I'm using the Build tool of Sublime Text 2 for Python 3.6.3

Comment: See also: [How to restore a builtin that I overwrote by accident?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152760/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NameError you're getting in the second example isn't from trying to use `set` after deleting it; the NameError is from *trying to delete `set`*.

`del some_variable` tries to unbind `some_variable` in the current namespace. Outside a function or class, that means the current module's module globals. The built-in binding for `set` lives in the built-in namespace, accessible through the `builtins` module; `del set` won't delete that.

Since `del set` can't find a `set` variable to unbind, it throws a NameError.

Comment: To clarify: looking up a global variable will check the global namespace first, then the builtin namespace (where `set` resides by default). However, using `del` on a global variable will **only** attempt to remove the name from the global namespace. That's why and how the first code example works. Note that this does [**not** work for locals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31175666), because local variable lookup will only check the local namespace - same as `del` on a local.