# Using Tuple for Inserting into Command

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this script to take the contents of the tuple and cycle through using a `for` loop (I'm not sure where to put it in my code) and put the contents of the tuple in a command. For this example I've used `find` as the command. Depending on which option the executor uses `sp1` or `sp2` will determine how much of the tuple will be used.

```
import sys, subprocess, os, string

cmd = '/bin/find '

tuple = ('apple', 'banana', 'cat', 'dog')

sp1 = tuple[0:1]
sp2 = tuple[2:3]

def find():
    find_cmd = subprocess.Popen(cmd + " * -name {}".format(type)),
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, err = find_cmd.communicate()
    find = output
    find_temp = []
    find_temp = string.split(find)
    if find_temp[0] == ' ':
        print("Found nothing")
    else:
        print("Found {}".format(find_temp))

type_input = input("Are you looking for fruit or animals? ")
if type_input  == "fruit":
    type = sp1
elif type_input == "animals":
    type = sp2
    print("syntax error")
    exit()

find()
```

Comment: an aside, be careful when naming variables that shadow built-in keywords (e.g. `tuple`) because they will override the name of the built-in in that scope. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418007/1248974

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close, but you don't do what you're trying to do, that's just silly. You could do better.

Rather than doing this weird tuple slicing thing, just give them a real name:

```
import sys, subprocess, os, string

# No need for the trailing space here
FIND = '/bin/find'

fruit = ('apple', 'banana')
animals = ('cat', 'dog')
```

Alternatively, you could use a dictionary:

```
find_params = {
    'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'],
    'animals': ['cat', 'dog'],
}
```

In your comment you mentioned:

> my tuple is a bit larger and both variables use some of the same values...
>   This would keep me from typing many of the same values into two separate lists.

You can still take a nice approach:

```
cheeses = ('Wensleydale', 'Edam', 'Cheddar', 'Gouda')
spam = ('Spam with eggs', 'Spam on eggs', 'Spam')
confectionaries = ('crunchy frog', 'spring surprise', 'cockroach cluster',
                   'anthrax ripple', 'cherry fondue')
food = cheeses + spam + confectionaries
```

Even if you just need a subset, you can still do something like:

```
food = cheeses + spam[:2] + confectionaries[-1:]
```

You should take parameter(s) for your find command instead. Also, no need to concatenate and then use a format string. Just use a format string for all the things:

```
def find(what, cmd=FIND):
    find_cmd = subprocess.Popen('{cmd} * -name {what}'.format(cmd=cmd, what=what),
                                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    output, err = find_cmd.communicate()
    find = output
    find_temp = []
    find_temp = string.split(find)
    if find_temp[0] == ' ':
        print("Found nothing")
    else:
        print("Found {}".format(find_temp))
```

Now you can either use the variables, or what they asked for:

```
type_input = input("Are you looking for fruit or animals? ")
try:
    find(find_params[type_input])
except KeyError:
    sys.exit('Unknown parameter {!r}'.format(type_input))

# Or use the variables
if type_input  == "fruit":
    find(fruit)
elif type_input == "animals":
    find(animals)
else:
    sys.exit('Unknown parameter {!r}'.format(type_input))
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you for sharing. Now, it's my fault for not clearly explaining my issue, but in my real world issue my tuple is a bit larger and both variables use some of the same values. For example `sp1 = tuple[0:10]` and `sp2 = tuple[0:20]`.  This would keep me from typing many of the same values into two separate lists.

Comment: I'd still give them more appropriate names than `sp1` and `sp2`. I'll update my question with some examples.

Comment: Thank you for updating your answer. This really helps.